# How to delimit PostgreSQL trigger procedure name?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

For example, in Perl you delimit a variable like so:

```
${foo}_bar
```

I have a trigger in PostgreSQL borrowed from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/whf3-a/hierarchical-data-in-postgres) that I am trying to make generic to work with multiple tables. Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_parent_path() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    PATH ltree;
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parent_id IS NULL THEN
        NEW.parent_path = 'root'::ltree;
    ELSEIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR OLD.parent_id IS NULL OR OLD.parent_id != NEW.parent_id THEN
        SELECT parent_path || TG_TABLE_NAME_id::text FROM TG_TABLE_NAME WHERE TG_TABLE_NAME_id = NEW.parent_id INTO PATH;
        IF PATH IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid parent_id %', NEW.parent_id;
        END IF;
        NEW.parent_path = PATH;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Each table that I am using this trigger against has a primary key like table_id (e.g., skill_id, level_id, etc). What I am trying to do is say `WHERE skill_id = NEW.parent_id` (for whatever table it's called against), thus the reason I am saying `WHERE TG_TABLE_NAME_id = NEW.parent_id`. What I'm wondering is how do I delimit TG_TABLE_NAME (trigger procedure) from _id?

Or, is there a better way to do this? Maybe I'm just going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLpgSQL has one fundamental rule - **plpgsql variable cannot be used as table name or column name in embedded SQL**. But there are a dynamic SQL - next way, how to execute SQL query. Dynamic SQL is a query generated in runtime from string (or string expression). There a PLpgSQL variable can be used everywhere. So your query fragment:

```
SELECT TG_TABLE_NAME_id::text FROM TG_TABLE_NAME ...
```

is wrong in more points, and should not work ever. But the dynamic query (PLpgSQL statement `EXECUTE`) should to work

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT %I FROM %I ...', 
                TG_TABLE_NAME || '_id', TG_TABLE_NAME) INTO path;
```

Related documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN